# class name and then the tag name contains the distinguish text

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have class name active and then there is unique text called active text in span(which is nested). Class name active is the unique among other class names then nested text is unique. How would i click on that. I have used following methods.

```
  FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='active']//*[contains(.,'active text')]"));
```

also i tried

```
  findelement(BY.xpath(//li[@class='active']//div//div//div//span[contains(.,'active text')]"))
```

also tried this

```
  FindElement(By.XPath("//li[contains(@class,'active')] and //span[contains(.,'active text')]")).Text;
```

Every time i get no such element found
ANythoughts
this is the html code

```
<li class="active">
 <div class="a">
  <div class="b">
   <div class="c">
    <h1></h1>
     <h3 class="d"> some text</h3>
      <div class="e">
       <span class="f">
         Active Text</span>
</div></div></div></div>
</li>
```

Comment: Please add the html source.

Comment: edited in the question

Comment: Xpath contain is case sensative. Try:   FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='active']//*[contains(.,'Active Text')]"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what worked for me was this,

FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.active")).FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(.,'Active Text')]"));

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.active span.f"));
  ```
- `XPath` 1:

  ```
  FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='active']//span[normalize-space()='Active Text']"));
  ```
- `XPath` 2:

  ```
  FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='active']//span[@class='f' and normalize-space()='Active Text']"));
  ```

Comment: Do i need to insert text() after normalize or not?

Comment: @Newbie You won't need

Comment: if i want to use it for the      <h3 class="d">another text</h3> do i use the same way?

Comment: still gettting no such element

Answer (score 0):

```
FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='active']//span[contains(text(),'Active Text')]"));
```

OR

```
FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='active']//span[@class='f' and contains(text(),'Active Text')]"));
```

Please try the above code. both will work. also, let me know if clarification is required